# How to filter documents in MongoDB and Spring boot

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, filter

I am creating a Spring boot where I have "articulos" documents. I want to retrieve them from the DB depending on their fields value but I can not seem to achieve it with the examples I found in this website or anywhere else. This is because I see someone people  use `mongoTemplate` which I assume is the interface class I have created for my repository but when I try to use that it says the method wasn't found.

This is what I am trying to do:

```
    Query query = new Query();
    query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("name").ne("Eric"));
    List<Articulo> articulos = this.articuloRepository.find(query, Articulo.class);
```

`articulosRepository` is just and empty interface with all the annotations needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the below repository method in `ArticulosRepository`

```
List<Articulo> findByNameNot(String name);
```

Use like

```
List<Articulo> articulos = this.articuloRepository.findByNameNot("Eric");
```

Comment: the thing is I need to use more criterias not only by different name, so I must use Query. I didn't know this that you posted tho

Comment: Spring boot provides you mongotemplate bean. Just autowire that into your service class and use the mongotemplate find method. Something like `@Autowired
  public MongoTemplate template;` and `template.find(query, Articulo.class);`

Answer (score 0):

In your repository interface create a named query with your property like below if you have name in your document then method will be:

```
List<Articulo> articulos = findByName(String name);
```

Call this from your service by @Autowired repository.